# Sorting Multiple Directory Entries in Ruby

Tags: ruby

If I have the following files And they have the following paths (changed for simplicity)

```
array = ["root_path/dir1/a/file.jpg",
"root_path/dir1/a/file2.jpg",
"root_path/dir1/b/file3.jpg",
"root_path/dir2/c/file4.jpg"]
```

How can I sort them to get this sort of hash like this?

```
sort_directory(array)

#=> 
{ 
  "dir1" => {
    "a" => [
      "root_path/dir1/a/file.jpg",
      "root_path/dir1/a/file2.jpg"
    ],
    "b" => [
      "root_path/dir1/b/file3.jpg"
    ]
  },
  "dir2" => {
    "c" => [
      "root_path/dir2/c/file4.jpg"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: It all starts with `def sort_directory(array)` and goes on from there. **What have you tried**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one way of doing it using [`group_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by), [`split`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-split) and/or some regex

```
array.group_by{ |dir| dir.split('/')[1] }.map{ |k,v| {k => v.group_by{ |file| file[/\/([^\/]+)(?=\/[^\/]+\/?\Z)/, 1]} } }
```

Comment: Nice! And It would be great if you could add some _step-by-step_ to describe how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use recursion to obtain the desired result.

If `s = "root_path/dir1/a/b/c/file.jpg"`, we can regard `"root_path"` as being  at "position" 0, `"dir1"` at position 1 and so on. The example given by the OP has desired grouping on values at positions 1 and 2, which I will write `positions = [1,2]`.

There is no limit to the number of positions on which to group or their order. For the string above we could write, for example, `positions = [2,4,1]`, so the first grouping would be on position 2, the next on position 4 and the last on position 1 (though I have no idea if that could be of interest).

**Code**

```
def hashify(arr, positions)
  recurse(positions, arr.map { |s| s.split("/") })
end

def recurse(positions, parts)
  return parts.map { |a| a.join('/') } if positions.empty?
  pos, *positions = positions
  h = parts.group_by { |a| a[pos] }.
            each_with_object({}) { |(k,a),g| g[k]=recurse(positions, a) }
end
```

**Example**

```
arr = ["root_path/dir1/a/file.jpg",
       "root_path/dir1/a/file2.jpg",
       "root_path/dir1/b/file3.jpg",
       "root_path/dir2/c/file4.jpg"]

hashify(arr, [1, 2])
  #=>{"dir1"=>{"a"=>["root_path/dir1/a/file.jpg", "root_path/dir1/a/file2.jpg"],
  #            "b"=>["root_path/dir1/b/file3.jpg"]},
  #   "dir2"=>{"c"=>["root_path/dir2/c/file4.jpg"]}}
```

**Explanation**

Recursive methods are difficult to explain. The best way, in my opinion, is to insert `puts` statements to show the sequence of calculation. I've also indented a few spaces whenever the method calls itself. Here is how the code might be modified for that purpose.

```
INDENT = 4

def hashify(arr, positions)
  recurse(positions, arr.map { |s| s.split("/") }, 0)
end

def recurse(positions, parts, lvl)
    puts
    "lvl=#{lvl}".pr(lvl)
    "positions=#{ positions }".pr(lvl)
  if positions.empty?
    "parts=#{parts}".pr(lvl)
    return parts.map { |a| a.join('/') }
  end 
  pos, *positions = positions
    "pos=#{pos}, positions=#{positions}".pr(lvl)
  h = parts.group_by { |a| a[pos] }
    "h=#{h}".pr(lvl) 
  g = h.each_with_object({}) { |(k,a),g| g[k]=recurse(positions, a, lvl+1) }
    "rv=#{g}".pr(lvl)
  g
end

class String
  def pr(lvl)
    print "#{ ' ' * INDENT * lvl}"
    puts self
  end
end
```

We now execute this method for the data given in the example.

```
hashify(arr, [1, 2])
lvl=0
positions=[1, 2]
pos=1, positions=[2]
h={"dir1"=>[["root_path", "dir1", "a", "file.jpg"],
            ["root_path", "dir1", "a", "file2.jpg"],
            ["root_path", "dir1", "b", "file3.jpg"]],
   "dir2"=>[["root_path", "dir2", "c", "file4.jpg"]]}

    lvl=1
    positions=[2]
    pos=2, positions=[]
    h={"a"=>[["root_path", "dir1", "a", "file.jpg"],
             ["root_path", "dir1", "a", "file2.jpg"]],
       "b"=>[["root_path", "dir1", "b", "file3.jpg"]]}

        lvl=2
        positions=[]
        parts=[["root_path", "dir1", "a", "file.jpg"],
               ["root_path", "dir1", "a", "file2.jpg"]]

        lvl=2
        positions=[]
        parts=[["root_path", "dir1", "b", "file3.jpg"]]
```

```
    rv={"a"=>["root_path/dir1/a/file.jpg", "root_path/dir1/a/file2.jpg"],
        "b"=>["root_path/dir1/b/file3.jpg"]}

    lvl=1
    positions=[2]
    pos=2, positions=[]
    h={"c"=>[["root_path", "dir2", "c", "file4.jpg"]]}

        lvl=2
        positions=[]
        parts=[["root_path", "dir2", "c", "file4.jpg"]]

    rv={"c"=>["root_path/dir2/c/file4.jpg"]}

rv={"dir1"=>{"a"=>["root_path/dir1/a/file.jpg",
                   "root_path/dir1/a/file2.jpg"],
             "b"=>["root_path/dir1/b/file3.jpg"]},
    "dir2"=>{"c"=>["root_path/dir2/c/file4.jpg"]}}
```